# How to programmatically set Spring profile in Cucumber

Tags: spring, cucumber, profile

I have begun to use cucumber tests for my Spring application. I set active Spring profile by passing a JVM argument `spring.profiles.active=testProfile`.

Is there any way to do this programmatically? Something like:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(...)
@ActiveProfiles("testProfile")
public class MyCucumberTest
```

Using cucumber 1.1.6

Comment: How about simply putting in a static block.
public class MyCucumberTest{static{System.setproperty("spring.profiles.active","testProfile")}}

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the proper way to do it, but at least it get it working for me. I'm using cucumber version 1.2.4

I specialized the Cucumber junit runner to set the wanted spring profile in the constructor:

    `public class SpringProfileCucumber extends Cucumber {
        public SpringProfileCucumber(Class clazz) throws InitializationError, IOException {
            super(clazz);
            System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "testProfile");
        }
    }`

In the test use the SpringProfileCucumber junit runner

    `@RunWith(SpringProfileCucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/tests/cucumber/test.feature"}, glue = { "tests.cucumber"})
    public class MyCucumberTest {
        // ... the test
    }`

Answer (score 2):

This is becoming out-dated. The use of `cucumber.xml` is not applicable for cucumber-jvm.

I have a similar problem, trying to use:

```
@ActiveProfiles(value = "DEV", inheritProfiles = false)
@IfProfileValue(name= "ENV", value = "DEV")
```

with a command line of:

```
-DENV=DEV -Dspring.active.profiles=DEV
```

It seems that these directives don't work with the spring-cucumber library (1.1.5, at least).

Answer (score 2):

Extending on @perseger's answer, the following specialised runner allows you to use the @ActiveProfiles annotation

```
public class SpringProfileCucumber extends Cucumber {
    public SpringProfileCucumber(Class clazz)
            throws InitializationError, IOException {
        super(clazz);
        ActiveProfiles ap = (ActiveProfiles) clazz
                .getAnnotation(ActiveProfiles.class);
        if (ap != null) {
            System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active",
                    String.join(",", ap.value()));
        }
    }
}
```

In the test, you can then use

```
@RunWith(SpringProfileCucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(...)
@ActiveProfiles("testProfile")
public class RyvrTests {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an environment variable for spring boot to use as the active profile. Using the `@BeforeClass` annotated method allows you to set desired profile before the application test starts

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(...)
public class MyCucumberTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "testProfile");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also create an annotation to activate a profile for cucumber. It looks like this:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
    classes = FeatureTestConfiguration.class)
public @interface FeatureFileSteps {
}
```

Quoted from my answer from this question:

> [How to activate spring boot profile with cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203301/how-to-activate-spring-boot-profile-with-cucumber)