# How to activate spring boot profile with cucumber

Tags: spring, testing, spring-boot, cucumber, feature-file

I am looking for a nice way to active a spring profile for my cucumber tests.
The cucumber tests need to use a stubbed version of a service which is marked with:

```
@Profile("test")
@Component
class FooServiceStub extends FooService {...}
```

The regular service looks like this:

```
@Profile("prod")
@Component
class FooService {...}
```

**My requirements:**

- Run cucumber tests with mvn: $ mvn test
- Run cucumber tests in IDE
- Run cucumber tests on build server
- No need to use the -Dspring.profiles.active=... argument

Sources I've found but don't solve my issue:

- http://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-spring-integration (using @ContextConfiguration loader with SpringApplicationContextLoader.class which is not present in the latest version of Spring Boot, 1.5.2.RELEASE at the time of writing.)
- [programatically set Spring profile in Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612414/programatically-set-spring-profile-in-cucumber)
  (messing with system property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In more recent cucumber version (`6.11.0`) you need a class with spring configuration and you have to annotate that one, not the steps definition

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've not used cucumber since a while but I believe you on your word.

Answer (score 3):

**Update October 2021:**

The below answer is outdated and no longer the accepted answer. Please check the actual accepted answer instead!

---

**Original answer:**

I've solved this issue with an annotation that I put on my FeatureStep class.

**The annotation:**

*Note the @ActiveProfiles on it.*

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
    classes = FeatureTestConfiguration.class)
public @interface FeatureFileSteps {
}
```

The configuration class is very basic:

```
@Configuration
@Import(FooApplication.class)
public class FeatureTestConfiguration {

}
```

**Using the annotation:**

Adding the annotation to the feature steps:

```
@FeatureFileSteps
public class FooFeatureSteps {
    @Given(...)
    @When(...)
    @Then(...)
}
```

Now when running the Cucumber feature tests, either from my IDE, from the command line with maven or on the build server, my test is using the FooServiceSTub and my tests pass.